# Matlab - Pass struct parameters to exe

Tags: matlab, struct, parameters, executable

I'm working in matlab and I need to run an .exe file with a struct as argument. Is it possible and how ?
I know I can already run an .exe with argument like this:

```
test = ['...\myFunc.exe ', int2str(1), ' ' , int2str(2)];
system(test);
```

But I want know something like that:

```
A.a = 1;
A.b = 2;
test = ['...\myFunc.exe ', ??A??];
system(test);
```

I read we can only pass string as argument. I hope this is not true.

Florian

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass a string array as the parameters to an executable. Note that this is not related to matlab. To pass a lot of data to an executable, it would be better to specify a file which contains all the needed parameters, for example a mat file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I will try something like that so.